# JSHINT integration with MAVEN

Tags: maven, jshint

how to integrate JsHint with maven

say i have following pom.xml

> com.cj.jshintmojo
>      jshint-maven-plugin
>       
>          
>              
>                   lint
>               
>           
>       
>       
>           2.1.9
>          maxparams:3,indent,camelcase,eqeqeq,forin,immed,latedef,noarg,noempty,
>         nonew,-W033,-W099
>
> ```
>     <globals>require,$,yourFunkyJavascriptModule</globals>
>     <directories>
>         <directory>src/main/javascript</directory>
>     </directories>
>     <excludes>
>          <exclude>src/main/webapp/hackyScript.js</exclude>
>          <exclude>src/main/webapp/myDirectoryForThirdyPartyStuff</exclude>
>     </excludes>
>     <reporter>jslint</reporter>
>     <reportFile>target/jshint.xml</reportFile>
>     <failOnError>false</failOnError>
> </configuration>
> ```

If i use all strings(like eqeqeq,forin,immed,latedef,noarg,noempty except WXXX) in options tab then it works fine but if I use 2 or more consecutive JsHint options like (-WXXX) it gives error(bad option WXXX).

I need all the string values for JsHint warnings instead of WXXX